# Центровка блока с bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, blocks

Привет всем, есть три блока. На большом и среднем экране блоки располагаются на одной линии, на маленьком хочу 1, 2 блок на одной линий, а 3 - по центру. Добавил в класс col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3(все хорошо), но на большом и среднем экране блоки ломаются. Как сделать все корректно?

```css
.container {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.flex-container {
  font-family: "Gochi Hand", "Trirong", serif;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 1600px;
}
.block-1 {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 200px;
  color: white;
  background-image: url("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-RQQS6WqpT8s/WBJNCBcJfbI/AAAAAAAAJYw/5zGBbZdrN6g5sq4VhcXMxEVlNGZVLys8gCL0B/w530-h398-p-rw/working%2Bman%2B%25231%2B%25281%2Bof%2B1%2529.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 500px;
}
.block-1 h1 {
  width: 100px;
}
.block-2 {
  font-family: "Trirog", serif;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 500px;
}
.block-2 span {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.fl-1 {
  margin-left: 2%;
}
.fl-1:first-letter {
  float: left;
  font-family: "Trirong", serif;
  color: black;
  font-size: 4em;
  ;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.fl-2 {
  position: relative;
  buttom: 20px;
}
.block-3 {
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  height: 540px;
}
.block-3 .text-center {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5em.
}
.close {
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 40px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.close .btn {
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 100px;
  color: black;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.block-3 .post-1:before {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  content: " ";
  background-image: url('https://pp.vk.me/c626522/v626522683/330be/mYfyjq85g_o.jpg');
}
.post {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
}
.post:before {
  content: " ";
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  background: url(https://pp.vk.me/c623318/v623318572/44179/25Zbq1K2Dpw.jpg);
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.post .text-muted {
  position: relative;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>first page</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gochi+Hand|Trirong" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container flex-container">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- first block -->
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6  col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="block-1">
          <p class="text-left small">MARK MANSON</p>
          <h1 class="text-left">The darkside of the digital normad</h1>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" role="button">Travel</a>
        </div>
        <div class="close">
          <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="#" role="button">close</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--second block-->
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="block-2">
          <p class="fl-1">
            T<span>he acknowledgement that something came from another source. The following sentence properly attributes an idea to its original author:
              Jack Bauer, in his article "Twenty-Four Reasons not to Plagiarize," maintains that cases of plagiarists being expelled by academic institutions have risen dramatically in recent years due to an increasing awareness on the part of educators.
            </span>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="close">
          <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="#" role="button">close</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--third block-->
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="block-3">
          <p class="text-center">comments(45)</p>
          <div class="post text-center">
            <p>comment<span class="text-muted">3 hours ago</span>
            </p>
            <p>Hello, World! My name is Jane</p>
            <div class="post">
              <p>comment<span class="text-muted">3 hours ago</span>
              </p>
              <p>Hello, World! My name is Jane</p>
              <div class="post">
                <p>comment<span class="text-muted">3 hours ago</span>
                </p>
                <p>Hello, World! My name is Jane</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>

</html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>first page</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gochi+Hand|Trirong" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container flex-container">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- first block -->
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6  col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="block-1">
          <p class="text-left small">MARK MANSON</p>
          <h1 class="text-left">The darkside of the digital normad</h1>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" role="button">Travel</a>
        </div>
        <div class="close">
          <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="#" role="button">close</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--second block-->
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="block-2">
          <p class="fl-1">
            T<span>he acknowledgement that something came from another source. The following sentence properly attributes an idea to its original author:
              Jack Bauer, in his article "Twenty-Four Reasons not to Plagiarize," maintains that cases of plagiarists being expelled by academic institutions have risen dramatically in recent years due to an increasing awareness on the part of educators.
            </span>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="close">
          <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="#" role="button">close</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--third block-->
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="block-3">
          <p class="text-center">comments(45)</p>
          <div class="post text-center">
            <p>comment<span class="text-muted">3 hours ago</span>
            </p>
            <p>Hello, World! My name is Jane</p>
            <div class="post">
              <p>comment<span class="text-muted">3 hours ago</span>
              </p>
              <p>Hello, World! My name is Jane</p>
              <div class="post">
                <p>comment<span class="text-muted">3 hours ago</span>
                </p>
                <p>Hello, World! My name is Jane</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо обнулить отступы для "немаленьких" экранов

```
col-md-offset-0
```